# Constraints to resize buttons to fit any screen - Xcode swift

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I don't really understand constraints and have tried many different suggestions found online. All they seem to do is bunch everything up on top of one another or do nothing at all.

I have the following IPad application but I want it to work on any size device, mainly a IPod touch.

[image]

The page is simply two buttons that I want to remain the same no matter what screen they're on.

Any help on this appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to think about points of reference that won't change with different screen sizes. Sometimes you want things on, say the top left corner so you just do constraints to the top and the left.

I'll give you two suggestions

## Suggestion One

For your case, it seems like you might want to do constraints off `centerY` since you want them to be in the middle despite the screen size.

So I would make a constraint to "Center Vertically in Container" and then tap on the constraint and adjust it's value to negative or positive, so that way it's always X pixels above or below the `centerY`.

Now that's not going to be enough. it knows it's Y position but it doesn't know its height, width, or X position. So you need to add enough constraints to satisfy those.

A few examples:

X/Width: Two constraints to leading and trailing on each button OR Center horizontally and fixed width constraint. (again be careful with fixed width constraints since screen sizes can change, sometimes it's what you want though)

Height: Yeah just give it a height constraint in this case.

Note that this means no matter the screen size they'll always have the same gap between them (and maybe different gaps to the other edges).

## Suggestion Two

Use a container view, either a stack view (fill, equal spacing, vertical alignment, a spacing value for gap between) or normal view.
You can make the view a fixed height based off the height and spacing between the buttons you want. Then simply center that container view horizontally and vertically on the super view.

#### Nonsuggestion

There are certainly other ways (like using buffer views with equal heights constraints. So you'd have an invisible view on top, a view in between and a view on bottom. and you'd give those equal heights constraints and align the buttons to the edges of the invisible views surrounding them. As long as you gave the buttons a fixed height this would work for vertical constraints) but I think these two would probably be the best.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips! I'll try them out now and see if I can get my head round constraints haha!